# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dllAdditional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

```
    int Sinhala, Maths, Science, History, Buddhism, English, Group1, Group2, Group3, Total, Average;

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sinhala = int.Parse(txtSinhala.Text);
        Maths = int.Parse(txtMaths.Text); //Error is in this line
        Science = int.Parse(txtScience.Text);
        History = int.Parse(txtHistory.Text);
        Buddhism = int.Parse(txtBuddhism.Text);
        English = int.Parse(txtEnglish.Text);
        Group1 = int.Parse(txtGroup1.Text);
        Group2 = int.Parse(txtGroup2.Text);
        Group3 = int.Parse(txtGroup3.Text);

        Total = Sinhala + Maths + Science + History + Buddhism + English + Group1 + Group2 + Group3;

        txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString(); //Find Total

    }
```

}
}

I Can't find Total.

> An unhandled exception of type **'System.FormatException'** occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll.
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Could you please paste the entire code and tell me what line is causing the issue?

Comment: I would recommend you add a break point and debug through the code.
One of the text boxes contains an character that it cannot convert.

Comment: You would be better off using `NumericUpDown` control instead of `TextBox`.  If you must use `TextBox` use the `TryParse` method instead.

Comment: Which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: Maths = int.Parse(txtMaths.Text); //Error is in this line

Comment: `Maths = int.Parse(txtMaths.Text); //Error is in this line` What is the input to `txtMaths` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that one of your int.Parse calls has text (presumably from the Form you are collecting from) that isn't convertible as an int.  Hard to say more without seeing the inputs.  Better to use int.TryParse and then check if it succeeds.

```
if( !int.TryParse(txtMaths.Text, out int Maths)) //Do something if this is an invalid input
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: If the text isn't a "straight" int, then you may need to apply some formatting styles/providers: [Parse with FormatProviders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse (string s) method converts the string to integer.

If string s is null, then it will throw ArgumentNullException.

If string s is other than integer value, then it will throw FormatException.

If string s represents out of integer ranges, then it will throw OverflowException.

May be the value you are passing into textbox could have other than integer value so its givin FormatException .

Try using : int.TryParse(TxtMaths.Text) it won't throw error in above scenario as well ,it will simply try to parse the value if it fails to parse it will return Zero value rather than Exception.

For more clarification please refer below link :
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845439/Difference-between-int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and-int